# How can i get photos from albums? facebook c# sdk

Tags: c#, facebook-c#-sdk

I am using Facebook C# SDK and it's working pretty well. I want to show user's albums and it's photos on my site. I am using graph api. I did get the albums using this method :-

```
   fb.GetAsync("me/albums/photos", (val) =>
            {
                if (val.Error == null)
                {
                    IDictionary<string, object> dict = val.Result as IDictionary<string, object>;


                }
                else
                {
                    // TODO: Need to let the user know there was an error
                    //failedLogin();
                }
            });
```

How do I get the photos present in each of these albums?

Comment: Were you able to get the album default thumbnails? I'm getting an error when I try to do

app.Get(album.id + "/picture")

Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: �. Line 1, position 1.

Comment: @Praveen :- el_tone's answer is the way to go. You need to make a request to the url given by el_tone but replace `photos` with `picture`. You can also give in query string `type=large` which specifies you need a large cover photo of the album.

Comment: I have tried that Kar. Everything else comes back fine (photos, names etc.) but for the album picture. The SDK is not able to parse the JSON correctly for some reason.

Comment: OK here's the deal. Turns out, FB does a 302 to the actual picture url instead of returning a json. The SDK was trying to deserialize the response which was throwing an exception; since the response was nothing but an image. I'm checking for the ContentType and returning the requested url instead of the response. From FB's documentation, /picture returns "An HTTP 302 with the URL of the album's cover picture"

Comment: @Praveen :- That was exactly what i was telling you. SDK won't work. But if you paste the same url in browser along with accesstoken you should see the picture without any problems. I have tried that and it works fine in my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An [album](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/album/) is a graph object so once you have its id you can retrieve it like so:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/{albumid}/photos?access_token={token}
```

You can also use dynamics with the SDK (if you are using .Net 4) which eliminates the need to cast to `<IDictionary>` in the callback and makes for much cleaner code when diving through the graph objects.

Answer (score 0):

Hi why you dont use [FQL](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/) to query [album](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/album/) and [Poto](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/photo/) tables to get what you want :-)